# JQuery Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, iis

Please I really need your help had been trying to work this for days.

- I'm using JQuery jQuery-ui-1.10.4.
- I use IE 10 in my development in my localhost.
- On my localhost it works in the IE, Chrome and Firefox.

But when I deploy it in the server IIS and access the page it have an error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

But when I use Chrome and Firefox to access my page in the server, there is no error.

So I'm confused how to deal with this.

Please kindly help me.

The code is below. 'email_button' is the name of my button that when clicked should open a popup div dialog.

```
//get a reference to the element
var myBtn = document.getElementById('email_button');
//add event listener
myBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
$( "#dialog-form" ).addClass("visible");
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: since you are using jQuery... why don't you use jQuery event handlers.. like `$('#email_button').click(function(){//your code})`

Comment: jquery is supposed to work well accross browsers, might as well try it out

Comment: I had a similar problem where jquery was having this problem adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" /> to head fixed the problem https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-2-1-1-min-js-object-doesn-t-support-property-or-method-addeventlistener was the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#email_button').on('click', function (event) {
  $( "#dialog-form" ).addClass("visible");
  $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much RGS! I'm very glad it worked. Thank you also to all who answered.